# print function of 1 variable and 2 integers leaves gap between the integers

Tags: r

I'm trying to print out a simple line that contains the information of the number of rows and column in my data

```
dim(iris)
```

which contains 150 rows and 5 columns

```
print(c("The number of rows and columns are", dim(iris)), print.gap=NULL)
```

this returns

```
# [1] "The number of rows and columns are" "150" 
# [3] "5"
```

For some reason stack overflow wont show the large gap between 150 and 5, please see picture linked for better understanding

I want it to print out

```
# The number of rows and columns are 150 5
```

or even

```
# The number of rows and columns are 150 and 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c("The number of rows and columns are", dim(iris))` is a vector of length 3 and that is what is being printed where all the 3 values are separate.

For printing purposes it is better to use `cat` :

```
cat("The number of rows and columns are", dim(iris))
#The number of rows and columns are 150 5
```

If you want `'and'` in between.

```
cat("The number of rows and columns are", paste(dim(iris), collapse = ' and '))
#The number of rows and columns are 150 and 5
```

---

To use `print` you can make the string of length 1 which can be done with `paste`.

```
print(paste(c("The number of rows and columns are", dim(iris)), collapse = ' '))
```

Comment: I find it weird to use cat after using linux mobaxterm, but that did seem to do the trick, thanks!

Comment: You can also continue using `print`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Oh i see you, you update the length back to 1 with the collapse function, smart!

Answer (score 1):

You may combine `sprintf` and `paste`.

```
sprintf("The number of rows and columns are %s", paste(dim(iris), collapse=" "))
# [1] "The number of rows and columns are 150 5"
```

or

```
sprintf("The number of rows and columns are %s", paste(dim(iris), collapse=" and "))
# [1] "The number of rows and columns are 150 and 5"
```

The `paste` is needed because vectors as arguments of `sprintf` would get recycled.

```
sprintf("The number of rows and columns are %s", dim(iris))
# [1] "The number of rows and columns are 150"
# [2] "The number of rows and columns are 5"
```

You can use two scalars (i.e. two vectors of length one in R), though.

```
sprintf("The number of rows and columns are %s and %s", nrow(iris), ncol(iris))
# [1] "The number of rows and columns are 150 and 5"
```